# Javascript redirect concatenates url linstead of redirecting

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I want to call a controller action whenever a value is updated from a textbox.

**Note that this script sits inside the same view which will be returned from the Dispatch/Index controller action**

I tried doing it like this:

```
<script>
    $('#deliveryDate').change(function () {
        var date = $('#deliveryDate').val();
        var sDate = date.split('/');
        location.href = 'dispatch/' + sDate[0] + sDate[1] + sDate[2];
    });
</script>
```

And it works perfectly the first time the value changes (ie, the page redirects to `/dispatch/12122016`).

However, when I change the value again, it redirects to `/dispatch/dispatch/13122016`, so the value just keeps concatanating and this of course produces an error.

---

I tried chaging the redirect line to `location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Dispatch")/' + sDate[0] + sDate[1] + sDate[2];`, but now it just concatenates the new date on to the url instead of redirecting how I need it to... (ie, it navigates to `/dispatch/12122016/13122016`)

Is there ANY way of doing this without including the literal url path??

How can "clear" the current url before redirecting the action I need (which should just be `dispatch/12122016` ?

Comment: Is the `dispatch` route relative to any path or is it always absolute to the host?

Comment: @ryeballar It is just from the host. For example when debugging the full url is `localhost:60775/dispatch/13122016`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply prepend a forward slash in the URL, this should always dictate that the url change is always bound to be absolute.

As a bonus: I also changed your date concatenation after `/dispatch` into a join.

```
$('#deliveryDate').change(function () {
    var date = $('#deliveryDate').val();
    location.href = '/dispatch/' + date.split('/').join('');
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this by appending the forward slash. Because your concatenating the dispatch string on every redirect

```
<script>
    $('#deliveryDate').change(function () {
        var date = $('#deliveryDate').val();
        var sDate = date.split('/');
         Var URL =  '/dispatch/' + sDate[0] + sDate[1] + sDate[2];
        Window.location.href = URL
    });
</script>
```

Comment: How is this any different to my first attempt? (apart from the syntax errors)